# awscli redirect cache file to another directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, aws-cli

Im writing a Bash script to download some objects from S3. The user account that runs this script does not have a home directory available. meaning - the folder refered to by $HOME does not exist.

I have used environment variables to redirect the credentials and config files. This is working, the files are created in the new location

```
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/newfolder/.aws/config
export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/newfolder/.aws/credentials
```

I get a Permission denied error when running this command.

```
/usr/local/bin/aws --profile thisprofile s3 ls $BUCKET$FOLDER --recursive
```

It is trying to write to a cache file in the users home directory, but cannot because the $HOME directory doesn't exist.

```
$HOME/.aws/cli/cache/a5e04d49e9fc210124ee0431e237dccc5ed84794.json
```

I have tried to export HOME to a valid folder. This works but I don't think this is the nicest way to solve this.
This script works properly with a user account that has a home directory.

Assuming I cannot just fix the missing home directory,
Is there a way to redirect this cache file, or everything in .aws, to a new location similar to what I did with the credentials?

Edit: In addition to Anon Cowards answer showing where it explicitly calls the HOME variable, there is an [open feature-request to disable caching](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4374)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround you've found is the only real solution.  Basically, if there's any scenario where boto3 needs to use assume role, the [following code](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/88d780dea1684da00689f2eef388fa4c782ced08/botocore/credentials.py#L249) is eventually called:

```
    CACHE_DIR = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join('~', '.aws', 'boto', 'cache'))
```

As you can see, there's no hope of customization, since the tilde expansion that's done by Python's `os.path.expanduser()` explicitly uses `$HOME`.  Technically, the code that uses `CACHE_DIR` in `JSONFileCache` has an escape hatch to allow a different directory to be specified, but that option isn't used by any of the calling functions.